# how to open multiple url through code, we have a code but its for only one url

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

we have the following script and we are running it in google script editor, its working fine but its open only one url, if we want to open multiple url how can we do that

function is

```
function myFunction() {
  var js = " \
    <script> \
      window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/', '_blank', 'width=800, height=600'); \
      google.script.host.close(); \
    </script> \
  ";
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(js)
    .setHeight(10)
    .setWidth(100);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Now loading.'); 
}
```

Comment: I dont know about google apps script but in javascript/html you can simply do that by having several window.open(); the code will not terminate before opening all links

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "open multiple url"?  Could you please post the code that is **not working**? As far as I understand the code you posted is working fine.

Comment: You are right the above code is running, now we want to know if we want to open multiple url, how can we do that. What changes required or where to put multiple urls to open

Comment: this is working fine for me in vba, but now we want to do it with google script

```
Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Range("b2", Range("b2").End(xlDown))
        ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink (r)
        Application.Wait called
    Next r
End Sub

Function called() As Date
Dim newHour As Long
Dim newMinute As Long
Dim newSecond As Long
Dim waitTime As Date

newHour = Hour(Now())
newMinute = Minute(Now())
newSecond = Second(Now()) + 5
waitTime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)

called = waitTime
End Function
```

Comment: If you want us to convert your VBA to apps script you came to the wrong place

Comment: i know Cooper, we have just post this for for infrom you that we have find a vba code for the above work, and we have done my work through vba instead of script,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### With `window.open` you can open as many windows as you want

Sample to open two urls in two different windows:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var js = " \
    <script> \
      window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/', '_blank', 'width=800, height=600'); \
     window.open('https://www.wikipedia.org/', '_blank', 'width=800, height=600'); \
      google.script.host.close(); \
    </script> \
  ";
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(js)
    .setHeight(10)
    .setWidth(100);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Now loading.'); 
}
```